# Rally chart - column layout issues

Tags: highcharts, rally

I'm having trouble getting the expected results in a chart in my Rally app. I'm trying to get an effect as seen in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmckinney/L6f6G/) example, with a series that creates a 'box' effect around two other series.

However, when I render it in my Rally app, the `pointPadding` and `pointPlacement` properties don't seem to be having any effect. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

**Highcharts Example (see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmckinney/L6f6G/))**
[image]

**Rally Example (see initializing code *below*)**
[image]

Here's the code that initializes the chart in App.js:

```
  myChart = Ext.create('Rally.ui.chart.Chart', {
    id: 'myChart',
    chartColors: ['#00B7E2', '#A6A6A6', '#747474'], //, '#00809E'],
    chartData: {
      categories: this.chartIterations,
      series: [{
        name: 'Planned',
        data: [23, 65, 113, 131, 138], //me.chartPlannedBurnup,
        pointPadding: 0.25,
        pointPlacement: 0.15,
        zIndex: 1
      }, {
        name: 'Actual',
        data: [23, 65, 113, 131, 135], //me.chartActualBurnup,
        pointPadding: 0.25,
        pointPlacement: -0.15,
        zIndex: 2  
      }, {
        name: 'Hardening',
        data: [33, 0, 0, 0, 145], //me.chartHardeningCol,
        pointPadding: -.1,
        pointPlacement: 0.0,
        zIndex: 0,
        enableMouseTracking: false
      }]
    },
    chartConfig: {
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Weekly Status Burnup By Release'
      },
      xAxis: {
        labels: {
          rotation: -45,
          align: 'right',
          style: {
            fontSize: '11px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
          }
        },
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        tickInterval: 1,
        title: {
          text: 'Sprints'
        },
      },
      yAxis: {
            title: {
              text: 'Points'
            },
            maxPadding: 0.1
          },
      tooltip: {
        shared: true 
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
          grouping: false,
          shadow: false,
          borderWidth: 0
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: If something work for Highcharts, but doesn't work for a wrapper, then or wrapper is using old version of Highcharts, or it's buggy. Does Rally chart has some online docs?

Comment: Yes, Rally has extensive API documentation. In this particular case though, the documentation directs you to the Highcharts docs.

Comment: Then I suggest report bug to them directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Pawel is in track that this is related to differences in HighCharts versioning.
Rally's AppSDK uses Highcharts 2.3.5. Your fiddle is pointing to HighCharts' current version which is 3.0.1.

This Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/markwrally/jB8gK/2/

Which is a fork of yours, but pointed to HighCharts 2.3.5:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/2.3.5/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/2.3.5/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

seems to exhibit similar behavior to your screenshot from the Rally SDK.

I'll do some checking with Rally Engineering about plans/timing for when the SDK might be updated to use HighCharts 3.

Comment: Is there anything in the Rally SDK docs that indicates which version of Highcharts is used? I didn't see that but I may have just overlooked it. I'm having an issue with my IT department blocking fiddle.jshell.net today so I can't verify the fiddle you provided, but I'm trying to get that resolved. Thanks for the quick reply to my support ticket!

Comment: It appears that the SDK's version of HighCharts is not documented anywhere. Sorry about that - it certainly would help avoid confusion if it was. I've submitted a request to include Highcharts version in the docs page for Rally.ui.chart.Chart.

Comment: W/r/t an update to the HighCharts version in the SDK, unfortunately based on feedback from engineering, I don't know of a firm date. Usually our SDK gets an upgrade in time for the RallyON conference (early June), but there's not a guarantee of either an upgrade by that time, or that the upgrade will include a newer version of highcharts. Apologies I can't provide a better answer in this regard.

Comment: And - here's a quick/dirty attempt at documenting this publicly :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22538776/what-version-of-highcharts-is-bundled-with-rallys-appsdk2

Comment: I got the issue straightened out with my IT department, and was able to view your Fiddle. As you indicated, this is exhibiting the same behavior I'm seeing in my Rally app. Thanks for all your help, especially going so far as to post the question about which Highcharts version is being used in the SDK.